# resize vim viewports automatically while switching them

Tags: vim, viewport, vi

How can I get vim to automatically change the view-port width while switching view-ports?

Lets say I am looking at 5 files simultaneously. I have set my left view-port width to 80 column. When I rotate across viewports (`ctrl W + r`) I would like my next file to appear in my left view-port and with 80 column width.
Opening multiple files and switching (`:n and :prev`) is not an option as i want it integrated with my cscope tags.

Comment: `:%s/\vview[-]{-}port/window/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to just keep your current window at 80 columns wide, you can just `:set winwidth=80` then whichever window you cursor is in will get to be 80 columns wide.